# how to reverse the order from last to first of an char array

Tags: java

I want to reverse any string input given by the user, for example, if the input was "qwerty" the out put should be "ytrewq".

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String A=sc.next();

    char[] test1 = A.toCharArray();
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    char[] test2 = test1;

    for (i=0; i<test1.length;i++){

        j = test1.length-(i+1);
        test2[i]=test1[j];         
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    for ( i=0; i<test2.length; i++){
        System.out.print(test2[i]+" ");
    }            
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Please tell whats wrong with this code, because when i do the loop on paper it works !!
And please tell me if it is the best way to do it.

Comment: Just so that we're all on the same page here:  what do you intend for `char[] test2 = test1;` to accomplish?  A *copy* of the contents of the array `test1` into the array `test2`, or something else?

Comment: `char[] test2 = test1;` does **not** create a second array.

Comment: test2 = test1 does a reference copy, effectively telling test2 that it is the same object as test1. Writing test2[i]=test1[j] in this context is the same as test1[i]=test1[j].

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shorter way to reverse the user input String

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
    String input = scanner.nextLine();

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(input.split("")));

    Collections.reverse(list);

    for (String str : list) {
        System.out.print(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in place:

```
for (i=0; i<test1.length/2; i++){
    char tmp = test1[i];
    test1[i] = test1[test1.length - i - 1];
    test1[test1.length - i - 1] = tmp;
}
```